# MapThread, Manipulate, Filter in Mathematica

Tags: select, wolfram-mathematica

I hope to be able to name that question properly soon.

Please Consider :

```
list1 = Tuples[Range[1, 5], 2];

list2 = Tuples[Range[3, 7], 2];
```

**I use the below mechanism to display all filtered eye fixations during a display. **

```
Manipulate[Row[
               MapThread[Function[{list},
                         Graphics[
                         Point[{#[[1]], #[[2]]}]& /@ Select[list,
                                                     (#[[1]] > f1 && #[[2]] > f2) &], 
                         Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 10}}]], 
              {{list1, list2}}]], 
{f1, 0, 10}, {f2, 0, 10}]
```

Now, I would like to display each fixation (point) one at a time, cumulatively.

That is :

Given

```
list1 = {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {1, 5}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, 
         {2, 5}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 3}, {3, 4}, {3, 5}, {4, 1}, {4, 2}, {4, 3}, 
         {4, 4}, {4, 5}, {5, 1}, {5, 2}, {5, 3}, {5, 4}, {5, 5}}
```

Use a slider to display the 1 to 25 Points here. But after filter the 1 to Length@Filtered Data

The Slider that control the Fixation number has yet a fixed boundary (25) , whereas it should have one equal to the Length of the filtered list.

But there is 2 due to `Mapthread`.

And I cannot extend the `Mapthread` to the Manipulate Control, could I ?

```
Manipulate[Row[MapThread[Function[{list},
                         Graphics[
                         Point[{#[[1]], #[[2]]}]& /@ Select[list,
                                                     (#[[1]] > f1 && #[[2]] > f2) &]
                                                     [[1 ;; dd, All]], 
                         Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 10}}]], 
              {{list1, list2}}]], 
{f1, 0, 10}, {f2, 0, 10},{dd,0,25}]
```

Comment: I am tryoing to understand _Now, I would like to display each fixation (point) one at a time, cumulatively._

Comment: @Belisarius, I hope this is better. It is hard for me to abstract from the real case, I will upload my nb. to show the real context.

Comment: @ Belisarius, NB uploaded at http://www.laeh500.com/LAEH/Voronoi.html I had never truly coded 1 month and a half ago so this notebook is truly the forums one as well. I would have never got anywhere close to that without those 38 questions and amazing answers ! I left open the problematic Manipulate but you can observe the bug manipulating the Steps Controls at the Bottom ! Many thanks for any help you could provide !

Comment: I still don't understand, sorry. You have TWO filtered lists, and their lengths _could_ be different ... so, which one should command the `dd` upper limit?

Comment: @Belisarius, I am sorry, I am not clear but what you mention is my exact problem : I would like to have to dd control but how could I then extend the `Mapthread`/ Or could I have only one that does not generate error in case  dd=12 for example ,  and there is only such position in one of the list ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like:

(Beware of code efficiency)

```
list1 = Tuples[Range[1, 5], 2];
list2 = Tuples[Range[3, 7], 2];
f = (Select[#, (#[[1]] > f1 && #[[2]] > f2) &] &);
Manipulate[
 Row@Graphics[Point@#, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 10}}] & /@ 
  Map[Map[f, {#}][[All, 1 ;; Min[dd, Length @@ Map[f, {#}]], All]] &,
  {list1, list2}], 
  {f1, 0, 10}, {f2, 0, 10}, {dd, 0, 25, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: problem solved thank you, I have to try implement this  in the am. What exactly did you mean with "Beware of code efficiency" is it relative to my notebook :) ?

Comment: @500 I am evaluating `f` twice ... for a lot of points that should be corrected ...

Answer (score 1):

Try it with `{dd, 0, 25, 1}`. This both allows it to parse correctly (closing brace) and keeps it real, so to speak, by preventing `dd` from being real valued.